# Listening to keyboard input all the time during execution of in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly

I want to wirte a program in assembly language using masm assembler. The program is about stop watch. I want to control this clock by using keyboard keys like by pressing S it starts. Again S it stops. By clicking space bar it pause. etc. But i have no idea that how to make my code able to listen the keyboard strokes during code execution. How i handle these events in my code. Can anyone help me

Comment: This is generally accomplished by writing a interrupt handler and inserting it in the right interrupt handling chain. This is generally known as "Hooking" an interrupt. The specifics of how this  can be accomplished vary with your hardware and operating system. You need to be very specific..

Comment: Actually i have no idea about handling interrupts. The operating system is Windows 8 and 64 bit intel machine

Answer (score 0):

For being able to listen to keyboard input all the time in background and do another work in

foreground, your program should be able to react to events. In DOS this could be done with a

TSR. Another possibility would be to check everytime, when the stopwatch increments the

display, whether a key was pressed, using function ah=1 of int 16h. If the carry flag isn't set

after calling this function, the user had pressed a key.

Comment: when i try to run this code in real mode i.e 32 bit mode it assemble correctly but does not execute. Why is it so?

Comment: @van Uitkon **If the carry flag isn't set after calling this function** isn't right because the status is returned through the zero flag!